# How to process large no of xml files and write into text file in java faster

Tags: java, xml, sax

I have millions of xml file in a day. Size of the xml files are from 10KB to 50 MB .

I have written SAX parser to parse xml files and write into text file .
I am creating 35 unique text files from all millions of xml files .
I have to parse these xml files in first come first basic manner so that order of the records is maintained .

I have to process the files very quickly.

Total size of the xml files will be approx 1 TB. 
I have not implemented multi thread to process xml files because i have to process it in first come first basis.

How to process all xml files real quick?

Before moving my code into prod i just wanted to check whether i need to rethink about my implementation.

This is how i read xml files and process it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        File folder = new File("c://temp//SDIFILES");

        File[] files = folder.listFiles();

        Arrays.sort(files, new Comparator<Object>() {
            public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {

                if (((File) o1).lastModified() > ((File) o2).lastModified()) {
                    return -1;
                } else if (((File) o1).lastModified() < ((File) o2).lastModified()) {
                    return +1;
                } else {
                    return 0;
                }
            }

        });

        for (File file : files) {
            System.out.println("Started Processing file :" + Arrays.asList(file));
            new MySaxParser(file);
        }

    }
```

I am not sure my processing will work for millions of the xml files.

Comment: Considered learning XSLT?

Comment: You should ask this in [Codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). They can help you improve you code better.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen now we can not change implementation ...

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen can we use big data mapreduce to process ..Will that help ?

Answer (score 0):

As you said,you have to process it in first come first basis .
You can think every xml file as a java method and then you can implement multi thread to process xml files.I think in this way you can save a lot of time .

Comment: I did not every xml file as java method?

Comment: Processing using big data like mapreduce will help?

Answer (score 0):

Immediately:

```
return Long.compareTo(((File) o1).lastModified(), ((File) o2).lastModified());
```

- read and write buffered
- be careful of String operations
- no validation
- for DTDs use XML catalogs
- use a profiler! (Saved me in Excel generation)
- if possible use a database instead of 35 output files
- check for a RAM disk or such
- of course much memory -Xmx

The last resort, an XML pull parser (StaX) i.o. Xalan/Xerces or plain text parsing, is what you try to prevent; so no comment on that.

```
Arrays.sort(files, new Comparator<File>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(File o1, File o2) {
            return Long.compareTo(o1.lastModified(), o2.lastModified());
        }
    });
```

Comment: So many thing i have to consider ..How much time i should to optimize ?Can you please edit in my code please

Comment: What about using big data like map reduce

Comment: Wrapping an InputStream with a BufferedInputStream does not cost. Reading DTDs (if you have them) from the net can be costly. A profiler is a bit of technology, but really helpful, try to find the bottleneck, to optimize. Makes all work verifiable and directed.

Comment: Big Data requires structuring the work too. I would certainly begin with XML. Concurrency like what Big Data offers might or might not yield a large factor or a small factor. For that to decide there must exist a processing model first.

Answer (score 0):

There are number of things to consider...

1. Is it a batch process when all files already there in `c://temp//SDIFILES` folder or is it a kind of event listener which is waiting for a next file to appear there?
2. do you have XSD schemas for all those XMLs? If so you may think about to use JAXB unmarshaller upfront instead of custom SAX parser

IMHO from first glance...

3. If it is a batch process - Separate parsing process from combining results into text files. Then you can apply multi-threading to parse files by using some temp/stage files/objects before put them into text files. 
   i.e.

   - run as many parsing threads as your resources allow (memory/cpu)
   - place each parser result aside into temp file/DB/In memory Map etc. whith 
     its order number or timestamp
   - combine ready results into text files as last step of the whole process. So you will not wait to parse next XML file only when previous parsed.
4. if it is a listener it also can use multithreading to parse, but little more may needed. As example, spin up combining results into text files periodically (as example every 10 sec.) which will pick temp result files marked as ready

For both cases anyway it will be "portioned process".
Let say you can run 5 parsing threads for the next 5 files from sorted by timestamp list of files, then wait until all 5 parsing threads completed (result may not be necessary a temp file, but can stay in memory if possible), then combine into text file. ... then pick next 5 files and so on...

... something like that...

Definitely, sequential process that large number of files will take a time, and mostly to parse them from XML.

Comment: anyway main point is separate parsing from aggregating and give a order number/timestamp to the result for proper aggregation (first-came-first) into resulting text files.

Comment: I am not aggregating it i am just parsing one by one it and writing it into text files.Is writing in to different text files every time make process faster insted appending to one file ?

Comment: h-m-m... you do aggregating actually. If you have million input files and only 35 text files as result it is aggregation. :-) Still main time consumption is parsing process. Which you can speed-up with multi-threading. BTW by separating process you can speed-up appending process too, by running 35 aggregation threads for your final text files. When parsing result is ready you can pass it to  appropriate text file appending thread... just a though...